# ZXing.Net not working on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, zxing

Im trying to implement the ZXing.Net nuget package to read barcodes from my app.

Im using the fragment version and it places correctly but it only shows the overlay, the camera image is just black.

Ive searched about and only found something about the Flashlight permission...

This is my code:

```
scannerFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();
//scannerFragment.CustomOverlayView = CustomOverlayView;
scannerFragment.UseCustomOverlayView = false;
scannerFragment.TopText = "";
scannerFragment.BottomText = "";
FindViewById(Resource.Id.imgBarcode).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.frameScanner, scannerFragment, "ZXINGFRAGMENT").Commit();
MobileBarcodeScanningOptions ScanningOptions = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
ScanningOptions.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat> { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
if (ScanningOptions.AutoRotate.HasValue && !ScanningOptions.AutoRotate.Value)
{
    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Nosensor;              
}
scannerFragment.StartScanning(result =>
{
    var h = ScanCompletedHandler;
    if (h != null)
    {
        h(result);
    }
    if (!ZxingActivity.ScanContinuously)
    {
        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Remove(scannerFragment);
    }
}, ScanningOptions);
```

And i have this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

I will be trying the activity way instead of the fragment, just in case it works.

The camera of the device works fine, why im getting a black screen?

**EDIT**

It is working on the full-screen version using this code:

```
MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();
```

Any idea why it does not work as a fragment?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile)?

Comment: @Pikoh im using this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fragment transaction hasn't completed yet. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()) states:

> After a FragmentTransaction is committed with
>   FragmentTransaction.commit(), it is scheduled to be executed
>   asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to
>   immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this
>   function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that all callbacks
>   and other related behavior will be done from within this call, so be
>   careful about where this is called from.

You can try calling `ExecutePendingTransactions()` after `Commit()` to force the FragmentTransaction to finish before you are trying to access the fragment.

Comment: Great finding.. This is very big issue and didn't found the solution elsewhere with this reason.. I got the issue of scanning not working due to this and this saved the block.

Answer (score 1):

`SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions()` after `Commit()` worked for me.